# Adding to a list when a variable is repeated

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm listing all the models and the avg mpg in a function.

Where I have

```
list1 = ['DODGE',20, 'BMW', 28, 'FORD',25, 'DODGE',28,'FORD',20]
```

and the expected output is

```
list_out = ['DODGE', 24, 'BMW',28, 'FORD', 22.5]
```

my code so far is

```
def average_mpg_by_maker(mileage_list):
    maker_list = []
    total_hwy = 0
    counter = 0
    list_makers = []
    for hwy_mpg, maker in mileage_list:
        if maker not in maker_list:
            maker_list.append(maker)

    for make in maker_list:
         total_hwy += hwy_mpg
         counter +=1
        list_makers.extend([make,total_hwy])
    return list_makers
```

which results in all the mpg keep on adding regardless of the model.
How can I fix it?

Edit: the counter is so that the total mpg can be divide by the number of the times the make appears for example for 
`'DODGE' appeared 2 times so 48/2= 24 mpg`

Comment: Your sample code seems to suggest your actual `mileage_list` is a list of tuples, each containing a string and an integer, not a list with alternating string and integer values.

Comment: Why do you write `counter +=0`?

Comment: Please add an example of input, with the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Why didn't you use a dict instead of a list? A list seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @JAW: multiple entries per car maker. A list of tuples makes some sense there; the alternative would be to use a dictionary with *lists* of mpg measurements for each manufacturer, of course.

Comment: I know, but you could replicate the dictionary in another variable, then deleting each one as you go.

Comment: I'll post an answer. My idea seems a little complicated.

Comment: Another problem with your sample input and your posted attempt: your sample input lists the maker first, then the miles-per-gallon value. Your code assumes the inverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to rely on a magical `hwy_mpg`; that value is simply the very last value from the `mileage_list`.

Store the *total so far* and the *count of entries* in a dictionary, keyed by 
manufacturer:

```
def average_mpg_by_maker(mileage_list):
    per_maker = {}
    for maker, mpg in mileage_list:
        info = per_maker.setdefault(maker, {'total': 0, 'count': 0})
        info['total'] += mpg
        info['count'] += 1
    return [(maker, info['total'] / info['count']) for maker, info in per_maker.items()]
```

You could also simply group the entries into lists, keyed on the maker, and sum the values later on:

```
def average_mpg_by_maker(mileage_list):
    per_maker = {}
    for maker, mpg in mileage_list:
        per_maker.setdefault(maker, []).append(mpg)
    return [(maker, sum(entries) / len(entries)) for maker, entries in per_maker.items()]
```

The above function assumes your `mileage_list` uses *tuples* per entry:

```
list1 = [('DODGE', 20), ('BMW', 28), ('FORD', 25), ('DODGE', 28), ('FORD', 20)]
```

The output uses floating point values, consistently:

```
>>> def average_mpg_by_maker(mileage_list):
...     per_maker = {}
...     for maker, mpg in mileage_list:
...         info = per_maker.setdefault(maker, {'total': 0, 'count': 0})
...         info['total'] += mpg
...         info['count'] += 1
...     return [(maker, float(info['total']) / info['count']) for maker, info in per_maker.items()]
...
>>> list1 = [('DODGE', 20), ('BMW', 28), ('FORD', 25), ('DODGE', 28), ('FORD', 20)]
>>> average_mpg_by_maker(list1)
[('FORD', 22.5), ('DODGE', 24.0), ('BMW', 28.0)]
```

The order of the output differs from your expected output because dictionary order is arbitrary and depends on the current [hash randomisation value](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary instead:

```
dict1 = {'DODGE':20, 'BMW': 28, 'FORD',25, 'DODGE',28,'FORD',20}
replication=dict1
dict2={}
return_dict={}
for key in replication.keys():
    if key not in return_dict.keys():
        return_dict[key]=replication[key]
        dict2[key]=1
    else:
        return_dict[key]+=replication[key]
        dict2[key]+=1
    del replication[key]
for key in return_dict.keys():
    return_dict[key]/=dict2[key]
return return_dict
```

I think this should work.